# Flexisel jQuery plugin showing slides in 2 rows

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm using FlexiselResponsive carousel jQuery plugin for one of my wordpress sites to slide some logos.

When I'm using less than 15 logo/images only then it's sliding in a single row only, which is fine.

The problem is that when I'm using more than 15 images then they are sliding in 2 rows.

I have gone through the documentation of the plugin but didn't get any solution.

How can I amend the plugin so that the images must slides in a single row always.

N.B.: I've included the screenshot how the slider is showing in 2 rows which I need to make in 1 row as it was showing earlier.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by changing the css value from 9999 to 99999 in the jquery css 
Here is the line where I have edited:

.nbs-flexisel-ul { width: 99999px; }

and it worked.It looks like the attached image now which I wanted to do.
Thanks everyone though!
[image after changes done in the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5czR.png)